# Access extra data from API response in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a list of client application requests in my app, I made a menu item in react-admin that displays the data perfectly,

I've added an `<Aside>` to my `<List>` and it is working fine, but my intentions for the aside component are to display statistics about all the applications I have, for that I've added to my API response the needed information and the response looks like this:

`data: [{id: "1", first_name: "user 1",…},…]
links: {first: "http://localhost/applications?page=1",…}
meta: {current_page: 1, from: 1, last_page: 2,…}
stats: {monthly_applications: 11, last_year_applications: 14, total_applications: 16}`

In the props variable I can only access the data section and I also have a `props.total` that contains the total numbers of posts,

From my understanding the info is returned from my restProvider from this part:

```
case GET_LIST:
    return {
      data: json.data,
      total: !json.meta ? json.total : json.meta.total,
    };
```

But when I try to modify this section and add any extra properties I cannot access it inside the list component and the `props` variable does not get the extra info, I also need to access the `meta` data from my API response and I'm unable,

Example I tried that didn't work:

```
case GET_LIST:
    return {
      data: json.data,
      stats: json.stats,
      meta: json.meta,
      total: !json.meta ? json.total : json.meta.total,
    };
```

When I console.log(json) I see all the data, but when I console.log(props) inside the `<List>` I only see data and total.